# How to insert value to database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm triying insert values to the database but I can't insert the value, I got an error message : java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
Here is my code :

```
    private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO book (title,isbn,edition,publicationDate,resume,nbPage,barcode,image,categoryId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
@Override
public String addBook(Book book) {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    int result;
    String message = "";
    
    try {
        connection = MysqlDaoFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
        ps.setString(1, book.getTitle());
        ps.setString(2, book.getIsbn());
        ps.setString(3, book.getEdition());
        ps.setDate(4,new java.sql.Date (book.getPublicationDate().getTime()));
        ps.setString(5, book.getResume());
        ps.setInt(6, book.getNbPage());
        ps.setString(7, book.getBarcode());
        ps.setString(8, book.getImage());
        ps.setInt(9, book.getCategory().getId());
        
        
        result = ps.executeUpdate();
        if(result!=0){
            message = "success" ;
            }else{
                message = "error !" ;  
            }
        }
    
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    finally{
            MysqlConnectionFactory.closePreparedStatement(ps);          
            MysqlConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection);
        }
    return message;
    }
```

BookImpl

```
    private static final String SQL_SELECT_BY_ID ="SELECT * from category where id=?";
private Category findById(String sql, int id) {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Category category = new Category();
    try {
        connection = MysqlDaoFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID);
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            category.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            category.setCategory(rs.getString("category"));
            
           }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        MysqlConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection);
        MysqlConnectionFactory.closeResultSet(rs);
    }
    return category;
}
```

I think that the problem comes from the servlet in this line :

book.setCategory(category.findById(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"))))

Can you please help I'm totally lost.

Comment: If you are not going to provide a [mcve], please at least indicate which line is throwing the error.

Comment: From the stacktrace you would get the line number where the error is occuring. Please update the question by indicating the statement (using comment) in which error is occurring.

Comment: Thank you for your answers the problem has been solved the sql query was not correct